# Why does my phone Micromax Canvas Spark reboot while playing Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Please help how can I solve that problem

Comment: Does your phone meet the minimum requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the device does not support the game.
I have answered this question already for the exact same mobile device.

Find it [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/275654/156437)